# Start a program once the other closes. Windows CMD .bat file edit

Tags: windows, batch-file, process, cmd

I have a program "Blah.exe" that I want start
right after the processe Blah2.exe closes.

Blah2 closes by itself in a variable amount of time.
Blah2.exe cannot run while blah.exe is running.
Blah2.exe must run only once blah.exe closes whenever that might be.

This is what i got so far....

```
rem Blah
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Blah\
start Blah

rem Blah2
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Blah\
start Blah2.exe
```

Comment: I'm not sue this is good way or not, use exec command at the end of the 1st program

Comment: Why is this tagged c++?

Comment: @James: +1 fixed it :)

Comment: Windows uses C++ as a coding language doesn't it?

Comment: Are these GUI programs or console programs being launched?

Comment: Blah is an actually program called therenamer which is a GUI program that gets launched by CMD in a .BAT file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `/W` flag in `start` which waits for the program to exit.

```
rem Blah
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Blah\
start /W Blah

**???***

rem Blah2
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Blah\
start /W Blah2.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Use   [CALL command](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html)  :

```
@echo off

call C:\Program Files (x86)\Blah\Blah.exe
call C:\Program Files (x86)\Blah\Blah2.exe
```

Comment: But then the blah.exe runs simultaneously with blah2.exe. once blah.exe closes then blah2.exe must open afterwards.

Comment: No..When the end of the second batch file is reached (or if EXIT is used), control will return to just after the initial CALL statement.